# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref.about')]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

firstly tho don't judge me i am abit new to the whole react native scene and the Javascript scene and learning mainly react native for my final capstone for school.

[My Firestore Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bl85.png)

In the picture you will see my database i am trying to do it with async but i am running into a problem.

**My goal**

Be able to add and eventually edit/update the users info to show on the profile page and the settings page through front end.

**Whats Happening so far**

I am able to get it working through backend work. Meaning I am physically going into my database and adding and changing it that way but thats not what I want to happen. i want my users to have full control.

**My about me section from my Settings Page**

```
<Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block>
              <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  Bio
                </Text>
                {this.renderEdit("about")}
              </Block>
              <Text
                medium
                secondary
                onPress={() => this.toggleEdit("about")}
              >

                {editing === "about" ? "Save" : "Edit"}

              </Text>
             <Button 
                onPress={() => { 
                 Fire.shared.addInfo(); 
                }} 
                title="Add" 
            />       
            </Block>
```

So far it's not an error but just a warning and i'm sure i'm missing more pieces of code in order to make it work

**My add info Section of my fire.js page**

```
 addInfo =  async({ about }) => {

            return new Promise ((res, rej) => {
                this.firestore
                .collection("users")
                .add ({
                   about,
                })
                .then(ref => {
                    res(ref);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    rej(error);
                });
            });
          };
```

what am i doing wrong here. I am so lost if anyone can help that would be great

Comment: Jus FYI: `add()` already returns a promise.  There is no need to wrap that in a new Promise object.  Just use the one you have that's returned by `catch()`.

Comment: @dougstevenson but then how could i go about adding new fields into my documents?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing several mistakes here:

1. You are wrapping with new Promise things that already returns a Promise
2. You are using `asyncawait` library instead of built-in one
3. You are catching error and not handling it
4. You are destructuring userInfo and then again building it

I guess what you are trying to achieve could be done like this:

```
class YourFireClass {
 ...

 addInfo(userInfo) {
    return this.firestore.collection("users").add(userInfo);
 }

 ...
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help but now i'm receiving an error  Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: undefined? what am i missing?

Comment: looks like your `userInfo` is not an object, it most probably is a string

Comment: console.log(userInfo) and see what comes there